# CentOS 6 - Cpanel/WHM DNS Issues

Tags: centos, cpanel, whm

So for some reason sslpro.xyz wont resolve yet server.sslpro.xyz and ns1/2.sslpro.xyz does.

Heres my IntoDNS:
intodns . com/sslpro.xyz

I have root access to WHM and SSH so please guide me!

This is whats inside of my WHM's Edit DNS Zone option:
https://gyazo.com/5614f92afae6e1744ec7d415238d09d9

This is whats inside of the edit options for sslpro.xyz in the Edit DNS Zone option:
https://gyazo.com/40fe19b105616419b1dba37da885a26f

Answer (score 0):

First... clean up all of your duplicate A records.

And then, make a record like this.

`@ IN A 10.100.1.30`

Here's an example zone using that kind of record.

```
$TTL    86400
@               IN SOA ns1.example.net. tucklesepk.gmail.com. (
                                            506
                                            1H
                                            5M
                                            1W
                                            1M );

                IN      NS      ns1.example.net.
                IN      NS      ns2.example.net.
                IN      MX      100     mx.example.net.

@               IN      AAAA    2001:111:2f29:196::3
@               IN      A       10.100.1.30
ns1             IN      AAAA    2001:111:2f29:196::2
                IN      A       10.100.1.2
ns2             IN      AAAA    2001:4978:12e:a::1
                IN      A       10.200.1.2
www             IN      A       10.100.1.30
                IN      AAAA    2001:111:2f29:196::3
```

It responds back fine.

```
[root@palaceredirect ~]# host example.net
example.net has address 10.100.1.30
example.net has IPv6 address 2001:111:2f29:196::3
example.net mail is handled by 100 mx.example.net.
```